# Display issue in PyCharm: very large whitespaces after leaving sleep mode

Tags: xorg, suspend, display, ide, pycharm

Here is the normal display of the whitespaces in PyCharm (very faint dots):

[image]

If I leave my computer for a moment, when I come back and wake up from sleep mode the computer, the whitespaces show like this:

[image]

I didn't find any other solution than closing and reopening PyCharm to remove those ugly bulky dots.

I am using PyCharm 2022.1.1 (Community Edition) on Ubuntu 21.10, Linux 5.13.0-41-generic x86_64.

Comment: I see this was cross-posted from StackOverflow. Please remove the question there if you are moving it here.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the solutions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug in newer versions of many Jetbrains IDEs:

- [Whitespace ligatures change opacity](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290366/Whitespace-ligatures-change-opacity)
- [Spaces displayed as big dots when switching between screen display modes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-66089)
- [Large bold square whitespaces after waking up the laptop](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289794/Large-bold-square-whitespaces-after-waking-up-the-laptop)

There are a few workarounds that allow you to remove the dot opacity without restarting the IDE:

1. Switch to a light theme, then back to a dark theme. No need to press *Apply* between.
2. Go to *Settings* → *Editor* → *Color schema* → *General* and uncheck/recheck *Whitespace Foreground*.
3. Zoom in/out on the font (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll wheel</kbd>, or some other way).